# FullCalendar and Drupal Rooms install issue

Tags: drupal-7, fullcalendar, dreamhost

I know this has been discussed numerous times here and on other forums but I have yet to find a solution that works in my situation. Drupal Rooms requires FullCalendar for the ability to book. FullCalendar module installs no problem. You then have to unpack the Drupal Rooms customized version of the plugin into sites/all/libraries. The libraries directory did not exist even though I am running the Libraries API, so I created it and unpacked the contents into the /libraries folder. I am constantly getting the status error that FullCalendar could not be found/could not load. It's there, I've verified it. I've tried with both the Rooms version and the FullCalendar version of the plugin....same result. Any help would be greatly appreciated! My site is hosted on Dreamhost, it is one level down from the root host. I have an htaccess file that directs the base url to the next level down directory. I'm not sure if that has anything to do with it but I haven't seen anything saying that that would be an issue. Everything else is functioning normally.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

This questions is old, but it comes up as a search result, so I guess it should be answered.

You don't really need to install FullCalendar module itself.

1. Enable Rooms module and all its dependencies.
2. Download [custom/altered FullCalendar library](http://www.drupalrooms.com/sites/default/files/rooms_fullcalendar-2.1.1.zip) and unpack it to
   the `sites/all/libraries` directory and make sure that
   `sites/all/libraries/rooms_fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.js` is
   accessible.
3. Download and move [Moment JS library](http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js) to the
   `sites/all/libraries/moment` folder. Check if it is accessible by
   `sites/all/libraries/moment/moment.min.js` path.
4. Clear the cache using `drush cc all` command.

It should work fine now. In my case it was step 4 which made me to look for an answer. Steps 1-3 are mentioned in the [README file of the module](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/rooms/tree/README.txt?id=HEAD).